# TFS webapi updates failing after updating to latest newtonsoft.json version 11

Tags: tfs, json.net

I'm updating Team Foundation work items using the UpdateWorkItemAsync method.  The relevant line of code looks like this:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.Models.WorkItem result = 
workItemTrackingClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, id.Value).Result;
```

(I think this will loom familiar to anyone managing TFS workitems with the webapi library)

The sample code I found in github uses newtonsoft.json 9.0.0.0, and works fine. 
 In my project I use newtonsoft.json 11.0.0.0, and the patchdocument fails to serialize (The body of the call is an empty json -  {} ).  And when i upgaded the sample code to version 11 it failed also.

This looks to me like a bug in version 11.0.0.0.  Is there a workaround?  Is there a serialization setting that i need to change?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce your scenario, only version 11.0.0.0 doesn't work. I have created a report at website below, let's track it:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/212774/api-that-update-a-work-item-field-doesnt-work-with.html

---

**Update:**

Here is the response from feedback:

> It looks like this is an issue with Newtonsoft.Json that will be fixed
>   in the 11.0.2 release.

You could use newtonsoft.json 10.0.3 temporarily, which is working.

Comment: Thanks Cece and Andy. 
FYI I ended up working around the problem by creating an "Object" object rather than a JSONPatchDocument, and then serializing it and adding it to RestSharp RestRequest (which worked really well because it handled the Patch call timeout much more smoothly than the HTTPClient.GetAsync method).